# Byte[].AsBuffer() copy results in Exception: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, usb, windows-10, win-universal-app, hid

I am attempting to convert a String into a byte[] and then into an IBuffer in order to set my HidOutputReport.Data field.

When I try to use byte[].AsBuffer() VS2015 throws an ArgumentException and provides "Value does not fall within the expected range" as additional information regarding the exception.

If I attempt to use DataWriter, the same exception is thrown when I call DataWriter.DetachBuffer().

If anyone has any idea why this might be happening or alternative methods I could try to get my String into an IBuffer it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Code Added

```
HidOutputReport outputReport = device.CreateOutputReport();

byte[] bytesToCopy = new byte[textBox.Text.Length];
bytesToCopy = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox.Text);

//DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
//dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytesToCopy);

outputReport.Data = bytesToCopy.AsBuffer();
//outputReport.Data = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(bytesToCopy);

//WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.CopyTo(bytesToCopy, 0, outputReport.Data, 0, bytesToCopy.Length);
uint bytesWritten = await proscannerSystem_device.SendOutputReportAsync(outputReport);
```

You can see some of my other methods I'm attempting to copy. It's worth noting that `WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.CopyTo()` *seems* to work, however I am missing the very first byte(I was attempting to figure out if it was an issue with my copy and given me running into this issue I am inclined to believe it is).

Comment: Is it possible for you to update your question with your code?

Comment: Hey @RogerHartley I've added some code however I don't believe it'll provide much insight.

Comment: I’m wondering if encoding could be the issue – you’re using ASCII encoding, but strings are UT16. I’m not convinced that’s the answer, because AsBuffer() is just wrapping an IBuffer around a bunch of bytes and it doesn’t care what those bytes are. But, it’s something to try – try using Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes() and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

First at all, to understand the problem, break the line where the exception occur.

```
HidOutputReport outputReport = device.CreateOutputReport();

byte[] bytesToCopy = new byte[textBox.Text.Length];
bytesToCopy = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox.Text);

//I used a similiar one (equals the customHID sample)
//DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
//dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytesToCopy);

// This line is to show for you that the problem isn't the bytesToCopy but the your filling vector (Value does not fall within the expected range).
var x=bytesToCopy.AsBuffer();

//Here, You take the bytes and put in report data. If outputReport.Data.Capacity was different of your bytesToCopy.Length the app throws a exception.*
outputReport.Data = x;

//outputReport.Data = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(bytesToCopy);

//WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.CopyTo(bytesToCopy, 0, outputReport.Data, 0, bytesToCopy.Length);
uint bytesWritten = await proscannerSystem_device.SendOutputReportAsync(outputReport);
```

*I checked in disassembly list that the trouble occur when program compare Capacity and Length between respectly the outputreport and dataWriter.DetachBuffer() that is similar your bytesToCopy.

To solve the problem, make sure that both are equals, if not, fill the vector or throw a exception to understand where is the problem.

```
 var x = bytesToCopy.AsBuffer();

if(outputReport.Data.Capacity != x.Length)
{ throw new Exception("Buffer didn't work. Correct the ranger filling the vector x"); 
else{
outputReport.Data=x;
}
```

in my case i did ...

```
DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
dataWriter.WriteByte(outputreport.Id);
dataWriter.WriteString(bytes_vector);
//IBuffer is 1(WriteByte) + bytes_vector.length

//in my case the capacity is 65 => fill bytes_vector to 65
for(int i=(bytes_vector.Length+1);i<outputReport.Data.Capacity;i++)         
{
 dataWriter.WriteByte((Byte)0);
}

var x = dataWriter.DetachBuffer();
outputReport.Data=x;

}
```

Don't forget that the first position is the outputreport.Id.

Regards

Guilherme Marques

Answer (score 0):

Compare the length of outputreport.Data to your bytes to copy. The first byte in your outputreport.data indicates the type of report you are requesting. Try to set your first byte to 0 in bytestoCopy and the add the textbox contents as bytes before using AsBuffer().